# Kibana - SearchParseException on histogram using custom timestamp

Tags: exception, timestamp, histogram, logstash, kibana

A **SearchParseException** is thrown on my Kibana histogram, although the data seems to be captured correctly. I am using a custom timestamp field that I called `logtimestamp`.

A log file line example would be:

```
2015-01-28 17:09:51,059 DEBUG [main] - processStatus = [MATCHED]
```

And the related `logtimestamp` field being added to elasticsearch:

```
"logtimestamp" => "2015-01-28T17:09:51.059Z"
```

I did set up the dashboard to use `logtimestamp` as the default timestamp and updated my filters' and diagrams' settings accordingly.

The following error is being displayed above my histogram, although the histogram itself displays data:

> Oops! SearchParseException[[alerts][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [Failed to parse source
>   [{"facets":{"0":{"date_histogram":{"field":"logtimestamp","interval":"10m"},"global":true,"facet_filter":{"fquery":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"\"matched\"
>   or
>   \"MATCHED\""}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"logtimestamp":{"from":1422454541705,"to":"now"}}}]}}}}}}}},"size":0}]]]

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. For anyone having the same issue, make sure that the **Index Pattern** in your Kibana dashboard settings is correct.